# Perl: How File::Spec->canonpath($path) works

Tags: perl

What is this method doing?

I simply don't understand it's purpose, and the explanation in perldoc is not helping me.

Now I need to update a Script that uses this method, so it would be good to understand what it is doing.

Is there a simple tutorial to understand the method?

Thank you

Comment: I am trying to understand what the script is doing. Then I need to modify/extend the script. What the script does is: 
1.) my $dir = File::Spec->curdir();
2.) my $path = File::Spec->canonpath($dir);
I just don't get those steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `canonpath` returns the *canonical* path that is equivalent to the passed parameter. That means it will

- Change all path separators to the platforms conventional path separator character
- Compress multiple path separators to a single one
- Remove trailing path separators
- Remove any superfluous `.` and `..` path elements

This is best demonstrated with a Windows path like

```
C:/a/b/../c///d/.//
```

This Perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use File::Spec;

say File::Spec->canonpath('C:/a/b/../c///d/.//');
```

#### output

```
C:\a\c\d
```

Unfortunately I can't explain the code you show

```
my $dir  = File::Spec->curdir();
my $path = File::Spec->canonpath($dir);
```

because the `curdir` method returns `.` on Windows and Linux systems, and `canonpath` leaves this unchanged. If you wanted to discover the absolute path to the current directory then you would use

```
my $path = File::Spec->rel2abs(File::Spec->curdir());
```

However this is better done with the [`Cwd`](http://metacpan.org/module/Cwd) module like this

```
use Cwd ();

my $path = Cwd::cwd;
```

Answer (score 1):

`curdir` returns the symbol of the current working directory. `canonpath` does different things on different OSes, check for example [File::Spec::Unix](http://p3rl.org/File::Spec::Unix) or 
[File::Spec::Win32](http://p3rl.org/File::Spec::Win32).

Comment: I tried it and I still don't get the purpose.
my $dir = File::Spec->curdir();
my $path = File::Spec->canonpath($dir);

print "$dir\n";
print "$path\n";

Both prints give me the dot.

Comment: @paperazzo79: Yes, as `.` doesn't contain successive slashes, double dots, nor triple dots, `canonpath` on it is rather a no-op.